# Raspbian Lite uses less cpu?

Tags: raspbian, cpu, raspbian-lite

Does Raspbian lite version use less cpu / memory than the full Raspbian.  I know the lite uses less storage for sure but not sure on the cpu memory.

I am running some time critical code I am thinking might improve if I switch to Lite because the cpu is doing less of other stuff?

I am trying to capture 2 images simultanously.  I have 2 pi zeros attached via usb otg to a pi3 and a simple python udp program that sends a message from pi3 to both pi zeros to capture.  However I'm getting images up to 100ms apart.

Comment: lite has no GUI so, yes, less resources in general are used when using lite

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? If you don't start the GUI, I doubt it will make any significant difference.

Comment: You have almost certainly hit on the wrong solution to your problem.  If you actually explain the problem you have we may be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

Raspbian Lite doesn't have any GUI. It has only a command-line interface. If you want to work on Raspberry with Lite version then you should have a basic understanding of commands and file system of Linux. And Raspbian Lite uses less CPU and memory uses because of no GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Having more software installed doesn't have any impact on the CPU/RAM unless you run that software. Run `raspi-config` and disable desktop environment, and after a reboot you will get a system which will be pretty close to Raspbian Lite performance-wise. If that provides the performance boost you expect, you could permanently switch to Raspbian Line. I wouldn't hold my breath though.